# Virtualbox guest (Win Server 2k8) has ip but can't ping anywhere

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I try to setup Active Directory on Windows Server 2k8 on VM (Virtual Box).  I have installed VB Guest Addition.

My problem is when I change the network mode to bridged, it can have a valid IP from the router, but can't ping  anywhere. `route print` seems normal:

```
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.107     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
    192.168.1.107  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

`tracert` gateway:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  WIN-6P5QDX8JQTY [192.168.1.107]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

No warning or error on Device manager. Change network mode to `NAT` make everything work. But I can't work with `NAT`. People need to access the server. I also turned off the firewall.

So I don't have any ideas what's wrong. Please help me fix this !

Comment: I set mine up with a 'Host only adapter', and then share the physical connection with it.

Comment: Will your solution allow another computer on the same LAN connect to the server?

Comment: Yep ... Give it a go